# Custom Module Configure block not alway working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I Have the following module:

```
module API
  class Configuration
    attr_accessor :endpoint, :raw_meals_url, :timeout

    def initialize
      @timeout = 10
    end

    def [](value)
      self.public_send(value)
    end
  end
  class << self
    def configure
      @config ||= Configuration.new
      yield(@config) if block_given?
      @config
    end

    def config
      @config || configure
    end

    def get_raw_meal_url
      url = config.endpoint + config.raw_meals_url
      resource = RestClient::Resource.new( url  )
      response = resource.get
      return response
    end
  end
end
```

I have the following initializers:

```
API.configure do |config|
    config.endpoint       = 'http://localhost:9000'
    config.raw_meals_url   = '/Food/RawMeals'
    config.timeout   = 10
end
```

I'm trying to test the configuration in rails console. The first time I save the initializers and run the rails console it works:

```
2.5.1 :001 > API.config.endpoint
 => "http://localhost:9000" 
2.5.1 :002 >
```

If I modify the Module, save it and rerun the rails console the configuration is empty:

```
2.5.1 :001 > API.config.endpoint
 => nil 
2.5.1 :002 >
```

If after the change on the module I save, without any changes, the initializers it works again.

I don't understand why

Comment: What do you mean `If I modify the Module` Are you editing the source code while the console is running? That doesn't work, you need to restart the console or manually reload the file with `load './my_file.rb'`. Or are you modifying it with some code in console? If so, show that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the problem is in Spring gem https://github.com/rails/spring.
Try turn it off

Comment: Yes you were right. I disabled spring and it works. Do you think is a known bug?

Comment: This is not bug. Spring has very extraordinary algorithm.
New code was reloaded, class variables reseted, but initializers (where you set your global variable) didnt run again